# Как обновить DataSet C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Пишу проект на С# (Visual Stadio) WindowsFormApplication.

Стандартными средствами студии выполняется добавление источника данных, в результате чего появляются объекты: DataSet, BindingSource и TableAdapter.

В установленном на форме datagridview в свойстве Datasource стоит BindingSourse и данные из таблицы в базе данных прекрасно грузятся в datagridview.

Потом в базе данных в таблицу которая грузится в datagridview были добавлены новые поля...
Проблема в том что никак не могу понять, что нужно сделать чтобы в dataridview начали грузится обновленные данные, т.е. дополнительные поля которые были добавлены в БД.

Помогите плиз.

Comment: в BindingSource и пр. новые поля тоже есть?

Comment: Не понял вопроса...

Comment: пардон, когда >> *Стандартными средствами студии выполняется добавление источника данных, в результате чего появляются объекты: DataSet, BindingSource и TableAdapter* в DataSet поля (столбцы таблицы) генерируются **именно те, что были на тот момент** , разве не так??

Comment: Ну да. Поля везде старые. После добавления полей в БД они не появляются в datagridview

Comment: добавьте по минимуму код, плиз
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask